# Given the vector field compute the integral along the curve $C$ drawn in the figure, with the indicated endpoints and orientation.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, line-integrals, parametrization

Given the vector field $F= (\sin y) i +(x \cos y + e^z)j + y(e^z) k$  compute the integral of $F \cdot dr$ along the curve $C$ drawn in the figure, with the indicated endpoints and orientation.  picture [image: here]

Comment: Note that the curl of your vector field is 0, so it is path-independent. You can just use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus for gradient fields.

Comment: thank you, helped a ton!

Comment: You might’ve suspected that to be the case since the problem doesn’t actually tell you what the curve is.